# Is it possible to query the graph in neo4j with just a part of the value of a relation's property?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am trying to move the info of data flows to a DB. The data flows are something like this:

E_App1 sends data to I_App1. I_App1 then sends this data to I_App3. I_App3 then sends this data to I_App5.
E_App2 sends data to I_App2. I_App2 then sends this data to I_App3. I_App3 then sends this data to I_App5.
E_App3 sends data to I_App2. I_App2 then sends this data to I_App4. I_App4 then sends this data to I_App5. I_App5 then sends this data to I_App6.
E_App4 sends data to I_App3. I_App3 then sends this data to I_App5. I_App5 then sends this data to I_App6.
E_App5 sends data to I_App2. I_App2 then sends this data to I_App4. I_App4 then sends this data to I_App5.

I am thinking of having a property named "OF" of the "sends data" relationship that will contain names of the data that is being sent so I can trace the flow of a particular application. Something on the lines of the below diagram. Is it possible to query the OF values, like "show all relations whose OF value contains E_App4 only"?

This is the first time I am trying Graph DB and I am thinking of using it as the relationships are complex. I am not looking for high performance here. Is there some other approach I should follow to be able to achieve the result of tracing the flow of a particular application?

Link to the diagram:http://s27.postimg.org/5qieemks3/Graph_Data_Modeling.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You diagram was a little complicated, but all you are asking is to find those relationships which are of the type `OF` and has the node type `E_App4` as the end node. There is no restricion on the start node.

So this query should work:

```
match (startNode) -[of:OF]->(endNode:E_App4) return startNode, of, endNode;
```

This ofcourse assumes the following:

1. the relationship will be directed from start node to end node. Hence any relationship from E_App4 as start node will not be counted. If you wish to count those also, remove the `->` and replace it with `-`.
2. The start node can be anything.
3. ONLY the relationship of type `OF` is considered. Mind it, the name is case sensitive. The relationship must be labeled with `OF`.
4. End nodes must be labeled as `E_App4`.

## Edit

Reading your question again `show all relations whose OF value contains E_App4 only` I guess I misunderstood you. You are asking can you check the value of the relationship. Yes you can. Here is the query:

```
match (startNode) -[of:OF]->(endNode) where has(of.property) and of.property = "E_App4" return of;
```

This assumes:

1. The properties defined in relationships have the key `property`
2. This will only check the relationships who has the key `property`. If your relationship does not have this key, those relationships will not be counted.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rash, that helped me. I got stuck in defining the filter but some search helped me in finding out how to use *. This is for others who may get stuck as I got:

The graph is somehow like this with a lot of nodes and confusing relations with Data property only carrying the identifying information.

```
z-[send]->b
y-[send]->b
w-[send]->d
x-[send]->c
q-[send]->c
b-[send]->c-[send]->e
also c-[send]->d
```

The Data property of every relation will have the source(s) it is carrying. So relations that are way far will have many sources defined in the "send" relation's "Data" property in the manner Data:"ABC,XYZ,QWR,SDF,TYOP,Zxcvb".

```
//to know which all send relations have ABC part of Data property
MATCH ()-[r:send]->() WHERE r.Data =~ ".*ABC.*" RETURN r
//to know which all send relations have TYOP part of Data property
MATCH ()-[r:send]->() WHERE r.Data =~ ".*TYOP.*" RETURN r
```

I hope this will help someone who is still getting a hand on all this.